# Выбор шаблонизатора

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте.

В общем, проблемка с выбором шаблонизатора.

Нужен лёгкий шаблонизатор, с минимумом функций, НО чтобы имело место компилирование. 
Т.е. я назначаю шаблон, переменные для подстановки столько, сколько мне нужно, и только после этого по вызову конструирую хтмль.

Гиганты типо смарти не подходят из-за их громоздкости.

Кто что может посоветовать?

Answer (score 2):

Twig / Twig / Twig / Twig

> компиллирование

Компилирование

> т.е. я назначаю шаблон, переменные для подстановки столько, сколько мне нужно, и только после этого по вызову конструирую хтмль.

бывает иначе?

Твиг, кстати, реально компилирует шаблоны в php-код.